# Hide a row (in a list) based on drop-down multiple selection on each of the rows (not on a single cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of "activities" in column B and each of them has a drop-down list for the status in column C. For each activity I can select "Done, In progress, TBD, Cancelled". What I want is to hide a row automatically (not filtering) every time I choose the status "Cancelled" in the drop-down (located in the same row).

[image: Screenshot]

### The code used is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("C2:C21")
If Target.Address <> Range("C2:C21").Address Then
    Exit Sub
Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Select Case Range("C2:C21")
    Case "Cancelled":
        Range("2:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True - ***I want to hide only those rows in which "Cancelled" is selected.***
    Case "Done":
        Range("2:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False - ***I want the rows to unhide if either "Done","In progress" or "TBD" is selected.***
End Select

End Sub
```

---

It's probably a terrible code for what I want to do...

Any idea on how to improve this?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Sara

Comment: Is there a problem with your code as is? I'd have thought you should use the Change rather than SelectionChange event.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `rng` object has never been used.
2. If you want to check the selection is in `Range("C2:C21")` or not, use a `Intersect` function.
3. The `If` statement can be completed without an `End If` only if it is one-lined. Otherwise you have to put an `End If` at the end.
4. `Range("2:21").EntireRow.Hidden` means every rows in `2:21` are going to be hidden.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = target.Parent.Range("C2:C21")

    If Not Intersect(rng, target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In rng
            cel.EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(cel.Value = "Cancelled", True, False)
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not sure the version below is fitted or not. In my opinion, generally this macro should only be run after something is changed, and we can only check the row who has been changed, other rows should remain the same state.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)    
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = target.Parent.Range("C2:C21")
    If Not Intersect(rng, target) Is Nothing Then
        target.EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(target.Value = "Cancelled", True, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The intersect function solves my issue here. The only thing now, is that the row only hides when I click in any other cell after selecting "Cancelled". I mean, I select "Cancelled" in the drop-down, the row stays, then I click somewhere else and the row hides. Ir work anyway, but if it could be hidden right after selection would be awesome. Thanks a tons!

Comment: You are probably using `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)`. Try `Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)`. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option, skipping the `If` and `Select Case`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myRng = Range("C2:C21")

    If Not Intersect(myRng, target) Is Nothing Then
        Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False            
        For Each myCell In myRng
            myCell.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(myCell = "Cancelled")
        Next myCell            
    End If

End Sub
```

The "beauty" is that the If condition is eliminated and the `.Hidden` is assigned to a direct evaluation of `myCell = "Cancelled"`;

Furthermore, the code is in a worksheet, as far as the `_SelectionChange` event is used. Then the `parent` worksheet of the range could be omitted, as far as it is taking the worksheet in which the code resides. So - `Target.Parent.Range` could be nicely skipped.

Comment: Since you're looping through every row and setting the `.Hidden` property on each one, there's no need for `Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False` - that simply makes everything visible just to have some rows that _were_ hidden be re-hidden.

Comment: @FreeMan - true, however the OP is using it, thus I imagine that there is some kind of relevant business logic behind it, making all the rows visible, including the ones outside the range `Rows(2:21)`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I will try those options as well. I'm more than satisfied with the support :)